# How can i have access to the dispatch event from the created method in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to have access to the data from the component, i can have access to it using the template but i actually want to be able to have access to the dispatch users details from the created method.
How can i have access to it?

```
<template>
<div>
<input type='text' class='e_pearl ep_pearl form-control' placeholder='Perle..' autoComplete='false' autoFocus spellCheck='false' :value='user.pearl_color' >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var colors = '#006064';
export default {
  mixins: [userMixin],
  components: {
    Sidebar,
    'swatches-picker': Swatches
  },
  methods: {
  created(){
    let {
        session: { email },
        $store: { dispatch }
      } = this
    dispatch('userDetails', email)
    console.log(this.$data.colors); // access to data from created
  },
  data () {
    return {
      colors
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    $('.ep_password').focus()
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried:

```
console.log(this.$store.state.user);
```

{**ob**: Observer}
session
:
(...)
userDetails
:
(...)

module

```
import actions from '../actions/user-a'
import $ from 'jquery'

let d = $('.data')

export default {
  state: {
    session: {
      id: d.data('session'),
      email: d.data('email')
    },
    userDetails: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    USER_DETAILS: (state, payload) => state.userDetails = payload,
  },
  actions,
}
```

action

```
import { post } from 'axios'

export default {

  userDetails: async (context, payload) => {
    console.log(payload);
    let { data } = await post('/api/get-details', { email: payload })
    context.commit('USER_DETAILS', data)
  },

}
```

If i try `console.log(this.$store.state.userDetails);`

Data are not available however i can see them from this.$store.state.user

But no luck!

Comment: @BrainMilot you question is not very clear

Comment: I want to be able to have access to the user data from the created method but i do not know how to do it because the data comes from dispatch. Thanks

Comment: @BrainMilot post your storage part also

Comment: Show the code for `userDetails` action.

Comment: I have added module and action code